# Girdview does not take a fixed width in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a few girdviws on my page and i want each to take the size i defined for it. I set the gridview width as follows

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" width="1020px">
   </asp:GridView>
```

It ignores the width and expand beyond the background border. I learnt from similar question in SO to defined each column width as follows.

The above failed as well. It really is frustrating> please any alternative would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use ***[Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx)*** controls to provide a width to GridView with the scroll options of Horizontal and Vertical.

```html
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Both" 
     Height="1020" Width="1020">
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
     </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

OR we can also use `<div>` to do something similar, using Overflow property:

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:300; overflow:auto;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the need for Panel here?

Comment: When GridView has large number of columns then it will usually extend beyond your page backgrounds which is of limited width, along  Horizontal lines. Using panels you can display grid view within the limits of page background and make this scrollable. GridView doesnt have not ScrollBars property.

Comment: if i am not wrong then we can create a CSS class handle the same thing there.

Comment: Of course you can create a class to do the same thing and you can put that class in a <div> instead as that is a <div> element is the HTML that an asp:panel responds to client with anyways

Comment: Yes that also a good alternative. Since the questions asks for an alternative , we can provide these ideas as they have been in use

Comment: Yah it does work. But it leaves the shades of the scrollbars which i don't seem to like them there. Is there any way i can hide them?

Comment: You can always modify such properties using CSS classes and give them the appearance you want

Comment: Can you pls help with a CSS example . I am kind of confused sir.

Comment: @Nuru: No problem. You can set the CssClass & ScrollBars property as: <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" ScrollBars="None" CssClass="hideScroll"></asp:Panel>.  Then define the css in your Head section as .aspx page as: <style type="text/css"> 
        .hideScroll
        {
            overflow:hidden
        }
 </style>

Comment: Check this link too: http://forums.asp.net/t/1935247.aspx?Can+you+remove+a+scroll+bar+from+a+panel+so+that+it+is+still+scrollable+

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="width: 1020px !important; max-width: 1020px !important;">
   </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/301449/Set-Width-of-gridview-columns-dynamically-when-Aut may be this link will help you